# Regex for username allows for more than one special character

Tags: python, django, regex

The regex I have is not working as I intend it to.

It should not allow for more than one special character and the special character should not be the starting character of the username. The below regex allows for more than one special character and it also for the special character to be the starting character.

```
regex=r'^(?=.{6,15})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@-_]).*$',
```

Valid Input : user@site
Invalid Inputs, user@@site, @usersite

I tried to alter the Regex it mulitple ways, but not able to achieve the desired output

Comment: What do you consider a special character?

Comment: for ascii characters `^(?=[A-Za-z0-9]+[^A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*$)[ -~]{6,15}$` or `^(?=\w+\W\w*$)[ -~]{6,15}$` if `_` is not a special charcter https://regex101.com/r/wg9xBS/1

Comment: Hi Nahuel. Thanks, but it's accepting special characters lile *#$^ etc. I want to restrict it to @_-   ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my solution... you can also find it under https://regex101.com/r/g33uf6/1:

```
regex = '^[A-Za-z0-9]+([@_\-\.][A-Za-z0-9]*)?$'
```

The regex starts (`^`) with allowing 1 or more (`+`) only characters that belong to any the categories A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9 (`[A-Za-z0-9]`), in regex terms `^[A-Za-z0-9]+`.

The second part allows any number of occurrences (`*`) in other words zero or more occurrences of characters selected from a given list `[@_\-\.]` followed by characters from the categories A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9 (`[A-Za-z0-9]`). In regex terms `[@_\-\.][A-Za-z0-9]*`.
But we want one or more match of the previous selection, that's why we add parentheses and the quantifier `?` followed with `$` marking the position at the end of the line

The regex above includes the following special characters:"_ - . (`_\-\.`). If you want to include other special characters, add them to the list between the brackets `[ ]` and make sure to use the escape character `\` where necessary, for example the dot symbol requires escaping (`\.`).

To restrict the total length of the string use the `{from, to}` quantifier as in `{6,15}`. Let's change the regex string to add total length check:

```
regex = '^([A-Za-z0-9]+([@_\-\.][A-Za-z0-9]*)?){6,15}$'
```

Note that here parentheses are necessary to inform the `{from, to}` quantifier whereto apply the quantifier. You can find this version here https://regex101.com/r/822V7R/1.

https://regex101.com is a great resource to test and design regex.

Comment: ^[A-Za-z]+([@_\-\.]).{,0}([A-Za-z0-9]).{0,}$ - I modified the regex to this and it suits me fine. But I have to restrict the min length and max length to 6 and 15.

Comment: I added a paragraph of the answer...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the special characters are, imagine that this is everything except A-Za-z0-9, we can do this with a simple regex:

```
regex='^[A-Za-z0-9]+([^A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]*)?$',
```

so we first require one or more non-special characters, and then optionally a special character with an arbitrary number of non-special characters.